# getting maps to accept a dynamically generated KML file?

Tags: php, android, android-intent, kml, google-maps

I have a button that launches the google maps app on my device via an intent. I want to be able to pass it a php page that generates a KML file.

I have done this on a website before using the googlemaps api in JS - but it doesn't seem to work on Android.

My php file is as follows;

```
<?php
     echo '<kml xmlns="http://www.google.com/earth/kml/2">';
     echo '<Placemark>';
     echo '<name>Google Inc.</name>';
     echo '<description>1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043</description>';
     echo '<Point>';
     echo '<coordinates>-122.0841430, 37.4219720, 0</coordinates>';
     echo '</Point>';
     echo '</Placemark>';
     echo '</kml>';
?>
```

Launching with:

```
final Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=http://website.com/kml_gen.php"));
startActivity(myIntent);
```

It launches maps, finds the file - but won't display it 'because it contains errors'.

Is this just not possible, or are there other ways to construct the intent that might work?

Comment: Have you validated the kml outputted? http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2007/06/validate-your-kml-online-or-offline.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the mimetype according to spec: `application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml`

Put this on the first line

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml');
```

Comment: that's done it. Perfect. Thanks. I suspected it was related to mimetypes, but wasn't sure how to change them in this case.