# Google Maps API map cutomization

Tags: android, google-maps, customization

I saw these maps in the websites of some universities and I just loved them:

http://www.uottawa.ca/maps/

http://www.washington.edu/maps/

http://map.nd.edu/#/placemarks//zoom/16/lat/41.6993288511065/lon/-86.23415926449582

I would really like to do something like that in an Android app. I've been looking for a way to do it but I've found no clue. Since I'm new to this API I feel quite disoriented.

So, could you please point me in the right direction? Give me some hints, somo tutorials or whatever you think it can be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the mapview easily enough using the Google Maps API. Then you need images of whatever buildings you are proposing to put on the map. The images can be added to a map overlay which will appear on top of the map. The tricky part then, is to match the geo-coordinates of your buildings to the map so that when a user scrolls the map, the images move as well and also to scale the images as the user zooms in and out.

Comment: So you're telling me to do what this tutorial says but with high coordinate precision? http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html Isn't there a most friendly way of doing it? What about the KML files, are they good for this? What about overlaying polygons with the API?

Comment: Yeah, that would be my approach. Apparently you can use KML files : see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982853/android-how-to-load-kml although there appear to be memory issues. I don't think you can draw directly onto the map canvas but would have to draw polygons into an overlay; either way you still have the issues with positioning and scaling.