# Loading KML from web in Android Maps app

Tags: php, android, google-maps, kml

I've created a web view of Google maps that allows a user to click on a map and submit a quiz question. That data then goes to a server and is output as a [KML](http://node01.geospatial.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/user19/outputKMLQuiz.php). It's very simple but I'd quite like to parse (right word?) this KML into an Android app I've been working on so that the user's points show up. Is this possible?

At present the Android app is simple too and just shows up some pre-defined points that when tapped display the questions, has radio buttons for answers and then displays a little toast popup showing the correct answer.

**Question: how can I load this [KML](http://node01.geospatial.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/user19/outputKMLQuiz.php) into a map on Android?**

Comment: Hava a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982853/android-how-to-load-kml

Comment: Check out : https://github.com/Ekito/Simple-KML and https://github.com/vashisthg/AndroidKMLParser/tree/master/androidKML/src/main